# Run-time error '50290': Application-defined or object-defined error when Excel runs in the background

Tags: excel, vba

I use asynchronous WinHTTP in Excel VBA to shoot requests to a website. After the reply is received, a module is called which writes to the sheet.

If the user does not have the focus on Excel, it will error out with

> "Run-time error '50290': Application-defined or object-defined error".

On this line:

```
pcol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WHA").Cells.Find("PRODUCTA").Column
```

I tried the following syntaxes as well:

```
pcol = Sheet3.Cells.Find("PRODUCTA").Column
pcol = Sheet3.Rows(5).Find("PRODUCTA").Column
pcol = Sheet3.Rows(5).Find(What:="PRODUCTA").Column
pcol = Sheets("WHA").Cells.Find(What:="PRODUCTA", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookAfter:=Sheet3.Cells(5, 1)).Column
```

I can force the focus back on Excel in VBA, but ideally, I don't mind if the macro runs in the background.

Comment: Just to be clear - it's not the way I write the code that makes it error (that's why I changed 5 slightly different syntaxes), but it's the fact that the focus is not on excel. If the user keeps looking at excel, it never errors out....

Comment: The module with the WinHTTP fetch would seem to know where it is. Can you pass the workbook or worksheet object to the module sub 'which writes to the sheet' as a parameter rather than let it discover them itself?

Comment: Hi Jeeped - thanks for your suggestion! I tried to do this, but it sadly didn't work (so I set global variables that stored workbook & worksheet and I tried passing it when triggering the callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
```

Or store your WB when you know you have focus and active it after

Comment: Thanks - but as I mentioned, I prefer a solution where I don't put focus back to excel when it runs.

Comment: If you store your WB when you open/create it as a variable does referencing it like WB.Sheets("WHA")... work?

Comment: Hi Travis, tried this, but it sadly doesn't work. AppActivate actually also doesn't work.... weird!!

Comment: I might need to see a bit more of your code. I cannot recreate the problem here, if you can recreate it (as simple as possible) I will have another look for you. I really need to see what macro is being called from excel, what is managing the HttpRequests and what you are calling once you know the response is in.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to trap the error and continue executing the code, this might help.

```
Sub Test()

...declarations...

On Error Goto Error_

...your code...

Exit Sub

Error_:
 If (Err.Number = 50290) Then Resume
Stop
Resume
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these two flags to false, while running the macro:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into this error but in another situation. While handling a workbook from Access. I 'm posting this just for future reference.

`AppActivate` needs the title of the application that will activate.

If you don't know the exact title at runtime, then write the following:

```
AppActivate Application.Caption
```

If you use another application like Access then set an object to Excel at the begining and replace `Application` with the object.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if someone encounters this...

I also use async http requests (module wrappers made by Tim Hall).

The callback is wrapping an Application.Run method; the issue I was having is that, due to the limitations of the REST API I was accessing, I had to rate limit my requests on the client side.

I did this with Application.Wait 
The responses were triggering http response event when the application was waiting and trying to do Application.Run

So simply replacing Application.Wait with another "wait" that allows events fixed the issue.

Alternative to .Wait

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub Halt(Finish As Long)
'Finish in seconds
Dim NowTick As Long
Dim EndTick As Long
EndTick = GetTickCount + (Finish * 1000)
Do
    NowTick = GetTickCount
    DoEvents
Loop Until NowTick >= EndTick
End Sub
```